# Load a json file, iterate through it and write every element in a new file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file, now I want to modify(change the key) of that `json` file. I am able to read through every item in that file but don't know how to write it in the new dictionary with modification using Python

Currently the json file is like this :

```
[
  {"detail": ["Jishnu Prasad Rijal ", " Biratnagar , Morang,", "M", "BBS, India", "1"]},
  {"detail": ["Lakshmishwar Prasad ", " Kharihani , Dhanusa,", "M", "BBS, India", "2"]},
]
```

But I want this in this format :

```
[{
  "name":"Jishnu Prasad Rijal","roll_no":1,"gender":"Male",
  "address":"Biratnagar,Morang","degree":"BBS, India"
}, {
  "name":"Lakshmishwar Prasad ","roll_no":2,"gender":"Male",
  "address":"Kharihani , Dhanusa","degree":"BBS, India"
}]
```

Help would be really appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Any other way to do it? Like reading through the file and writing it to a new dictionary with new keys.

Comment: Is the order in details always same? like `name, address, gender, degree, roll_no`?

Comment: yes, its always the same, just some details have no values of address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input_dict = [
        {"detail": ["Jishnu Prasad Rijal ", " Biratnagar , Morang,", "M", "BBS, India", "1"]},
        {"detail": ["Lakshmishwar Prasad ", " Kharihani , Dhanusa,", "M", "BBS, India", "2"]},
        ]
cols = ['name','address','gender','degree','roll_no']
output_list = []
for el in input_dict:
            x = el['detail']
            #print(dict(zip(cols,x)))
            op = dict(zip(cols,x))
            output_list.append(op)
print(output_list)
```

Comment: I would recommend taking out some of your debugging `print` statements, and cleaning up the indentation.  Also showing the output would be helpful!

Comment: it's working but it is printing the same data multiple times

Comment: now it's working fine but few more issues, every time I run the script, the data is arranged in different order. It should be as it is in cols, right? sometimes the 'gender' is first, sometimes the 'name'  and another issue is, some addresses are empty and in that empty address, gender is getting set. How to manage that?

Answer (score 2):

Simply using **`zip`**

```
keys = ['name', 'address', 'gender', 'degree', 'role_no']
x = [dict(zip(keys, i['detail'])) for i in x]

[{'name': 'Jishnu Prasad Rijal ', 'address': ' Biratnagar , Morang,', 'gender': 'M', 'degree': 'BBS, India', 'role_no': '1'}, {'name': 'Lakshmishwar Prasad ', 'address': ' Kharihani , Dhanusa,', 'gender': 'M', 'degree': 'BBS, India', 'role_no': '2'}]
```